# Regex for calculator display

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I was wondering if it is possible to make a regex for a calculator input with these conditions, the display starts with a `0`:

- the fist char can be an `+` or `-` sign (optional)
- if the first input is a `.` it should be appended to the `0`
- if the first input is a number it should take the place of the `0`
- the number can have only one `.`
- after a number I can have an operator `+-/*`
- the operator `/*` can be followed by an `+-`
- if the input is an operator and the last char is a operator it should take the place of the last char

Allowed input example:

`-0.548*-7+54`

Wrong input example:

`*354*/56-+45`

I could do that with a mix of `regex` and `conditionals` (I'm using React):

```
const displayPattern = /([+-]?)(\d+)(\.?)(\d*)([*/]?)([+-]?)/g;
const isOperator = /[-+*/]/;
const isNumber = /\d/;
const isSign = /[-+]/;
const lastChar = state.slice(-1);

if (value.includes("AC")) {
  setState("0");
} else if (state.length === 1) {
  if (isNumber.test(value)) {
    if (state === "0") {
      setState(value);
    } else {
      setState(preVal => preVal + value);
    }
  } else if (value === ".") {
    setState(preVal => preVal + value);
  } else if (isSign.test(value)) {
    setState(value);
  }
} else {
  if (isOperator.test(lastChar) && isOperator.test(value)) {
    if (isSign.test(lastChar)) {
      setState(prevVal => prevVal.slice(0, -1) + value);
    } else {
      !isSign.test(value) && setState(prevVal => prevVal.slice(0, -1) + value);
    }
  }
  setState(
    preVal =>
      (preVal + value).match(displayPattern) &&
      (preVal + value).match(displayPattern).join("")
  );
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question with the examples, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
^[+-]?\d*\.*\d+(?:[+*\/-][+-]?\d*\.*\d+)*$
```

- `^` - start string anchor
- `[+-]?` - start with an optional positive or negative sign
- `\d*\.*\d+` - optional digit, followed by optional decimal, followed by required digit. This allows us to account for whole numbers or decimals.
- `(?:[+*\/-][+-]?\d*\.*\d+)*` - repeating optional pattern of previous two bullet points with a required preceding operator
- `$` - end string anchor

https://regex101.com/r/srl7vj/1